# Implementing addFields with Mongoose(MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to calculate the average value of the ratings for a Product. Instead of calculating the average rating of the Product every time when we need the value. I calculate it every time someone rates it. I am expecting to see additional fields in the Document but for some reason `console.log('stats: ', stats);` is printing out an empty array and the fields are not added to the Document. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
const calculateAvgRating = async (id) => {
  try {
    const stats = await Product.aggregate([
      { $match: { _id: id } },
      {
        $addFields: {
          avgRating: {
            $avg: '$ratings.star',
          },
          nRatings: {
            $size: '$ratings',
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
    console.log('stats: ', stats);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`calculateAvgRating error: ${err}`);
  }
};
```

**Schema**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32,
      text: true,
    },
    slug: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
      index: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: 32,
    },
    quantity: Number,
    ratings: [
      {
        star: Number,
        postedBy: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

export default mongoose.models.Product ||
  mongoose.model('Product', ParentSchema);
```

Comment: your query looks good, you need to convert your input `id` from string to object id in match stage `{ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) }`

Comment: Unfortunately no change .

Comment: it does print out the result but no change in the Document

Comment: probably you are missing something, i don't see any other problem in your query. just make sure that input `id`'s product should be available in the collection.

Comment: should I expect the added fields in the Document or just in the print out of the `stats` ?

Comment: The aggregate function will only return the results.  If you want to modify the documents, consider a `$merge` stage or use `updateOne`.